# Using two supply rails (on supply and output pins) with 74HC595

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, led, current, shift-register

I have a 74HC595 connected to an STM32 to drive a bunch of LEDs using fewer GPIO pins.

[image]

I want to reduce the current flowing through the 3.3V regulator IC which supplies the controller, and want the LEDs to be on the 5V power rail.

Can connecting 5V supply to the SR output pins lead to any complications, considering that the SR is powered from the 3.3V supply rail? The datasheet mentions that "input and output voltage ratings may be exceeded if the input and output current ratings are observed."

The current ratings can be observed by using appropriate current limiting resistors. Is this enough to get the job done?

I can't provide 5V to the IC supply, cause the controller uses 3.3V logic levels, and 3.3V is not guaranteed to be interpreted as logic HIGH.

EDIT: The current carrying resistor values were from my design which used 3.3V supply, and I hadn't updated it in the schematic.

Comment: More importantly, are the LEDs "off" at 1.7V?

Comment: Another thing to consider: The current that seeps through the LEDs and the 595 into the 3.3 V rail, it has to go somewhere. The regulator typically doesn't sink it. So there is a chance that you will raise your 3.3 V rail a bit (if its consumption is low), which could have adverse effects elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good way of doing it.

This is even said in the data sheet; outputs should not be pulled above VCC, and 70mA total current should not be exceeded, and you are doing both.

If 5V supply powers on first, it will push current through LEDs and into the IC outputs which pushes current to the 3.3V node.

And as an output, the safe range for voltage on output is up to the 3.3V supply.

The assumption is that LEDs drop 5V down but they might not drop the voltage down to 3.3V, as that would be 1.7V over the LED, and LEDs will require at least some amount of current to drop 1.7V. So the LEDs could still be on even if 74HC595 output is high.

Assuming the LEDs drop 2V, the total current adds up to more than 70mA. The IC has an absolute maximum rating of 70mA, so first of all, the chip does not need to work because it is being used outside nominal operating conditions, and second, the chip is being used beyond absolute maximum ratings so it can cause permanent damage to the chip.

And you didn't ask but you could simply switch to a 74HCT595 which allows 3.3V IO signals while being powered at 5V.

Comment: "allows 3.3V IO signals" is a side effect of supporting 5V TTL logic levels, right? The controller output is 3.3V CMOS. Are there any other caveats to using 74HCT595 like this?

Comment: About the total current consumption, I forgot to change the resistor values after I changed the supply from 3.3V to 5V.

Comment: @nottherealfaraday It's not a side effect. HCT has CMOS inputs meant to support standard TTL voltage levels, and 3.3V CMOS outputs fulfill all requirements for TTL inputs. There is no caveats, perfectly valid usage.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just a first note: You are not connecting 5V supply to the SR output pins, there are the resistors and LEDs in series. These limit the clamp current to \$I_{OK} = {(V_{Supply} - V_{f} - V_{OH}) \over R} = {(5.5V - 1.4V - 2.8V) \over 330\Omega} = 3.9mA\$. I use quite pessimistic values here, and yet the clamp current is far below the maximum of 20mA.

Therefore, according to the data sheet, you are OK.

**But there is another point to consider:** Will an LED switch off at all? This current looks a bit high compared with the current if the 74HC595 outputs 0V (see below).

Therefore, I'm afraid you will switch between "bright on" and "dim on." If that's OK for you, you're fine.

Otherwise you need additional measures. For example, you can insert 1 or 2 diodes to reduce V<sub>Supply</sub> to cut off the current. Or use another 3.3V supply, separated from the STM32.

---

As I'm curious, this is the estimated maximum LED current when switched on: \$I_{OL} = {(V_{Supply} - V_{f} - V_{OL}) \over R} = {(5.5V - 1.4V - 0V) \over 330\Omega} = 12.4mA\$. I hope this matches your requirements.